# What does צו״צ stand for?

Tags: shabbat, mincha-afternoon-prayer, acronyms

After *sh'mone esre* (*amida*) of *mincha* on most *Shabasos*, we say three *p'sukim*, the first of which starts with the word "צדקתך". I've seen this three-*pasuk* paragraph referred to in Hebrew-language *halacha* sources as "צו״צ". What does that stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [Hebrew site](http://www.kizur.co.il/search_word.php?abbr=%D7%A6%D7%95%22%D7%A6&m=21) explaining abbreviations and acronyms in Hebrew.

צו״צ means 
 צדקתך וצדקתך צדקתך

This [Chabad site](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/2/598)
explains that צו״צ

stands for the three posukim said on Shabbos mincha.

שלושת הפסוקים שאומרים במנחה בשבת,

which begin with the three words צדקתך, וצדקתך,  צדקתך