# How to ordering Tsidkatecha, Vetsidkatecha, Tsidkatecha

Tags: shabbat, mincha-afternoon-prayer, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, nusach-edot-hammizrach

I see a beautiful [post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/what-does-%D7%A6%D7%95-%D7%A6-stand-for/44263#44263) about initials צו"צ
and I am wondering: in Sfard nussach and in Ashkenaz, the verses are in different orders (but in Chassidic minhagim (perhaps d/t difference between Polish minhag and Hungarian), Gur Chassidim recite as in Ashkenaz sidur). Here is an extract of the sidur [Zecher Menachem](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01774.html?dyn). The first order appears in the majority of sidurim Nussach Sfard, the last in all the sidurim Nussach Ashkenaz; Nussach Sepharadi is the same as nussach sfard (more exactly the contrary is right)

> - 1. צִדְקָתְךָ כְּהַרְרֵי אֵל, מִשְׁפָּטֶיךָ תְּהוֹם רַבָּה אָדָם וּבְהֵמָה תוֹשִׁיעַ יְהֹוָה
>   2. וְצִדְקָתְךָ אֱלֹהִים עַד מָרוֹם, אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתָ גְדֹלוֹת. אֱלֹהִים, מִי כָמוֹךָ
>   3. צִדְקָתְךָ צֶדֶק לְעוֹלָם, וְתוֹרָתךָ אֱמֶת
>   ---
> - 1. צִדְקָתְךָ צֶדֶק לְעוֹלָם, וְתוֹרָתךָ אֱמֶת
>   2. וְצִדְקָתְךָ אֱלֹהִים עַד מָרוֹם אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתָ גְדֹלוֹת. אֱלֹהִים, מִי כָמוֹךָ
>   3. צִדְקָתְךָ כְּהַרְרֵי אֵל, מִשְׁפָּטֶיךָ תְּהוֹם רַבָּה. אָדָם וּבְהֵמָה תוֹשִׁיעַ יְהֹוָה

The above-cited post enlightened me to the fact that the order is 'צו״צ' in the both. Is there an explanation for these orders?